# loading google maps data into searchable data structure

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kml

For my CS bachelors I am doing a Senior project using android and google maps.

My vision was to do a (relatively) simple Dijkstra shortest path using google maps road data. I was going to add elevation change along with 2D distance. I am doing well playing with maps in android but I am completely stumped trying to access google maps data in any sort of searchable form.

How would I go about accessing the data for say intersections of roads (lat/long) in a particular area?

There has to be a way to pull that data in some sort of tree form. It seems like it may be possible with kml?

Any pointers would be awesome.

I want my paths to follow roads but If i cant this is going to turn into an orienteering application fairly fast.

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into http://www.openstreetmap.org/ instead, they have the lat/long points of streets available for view. Google and others buy theirs, which keeps you from being allowed to access the raw information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can access raw road data from Google Maps (such information is very valuable - if Google gave it out for free I can see car navigation companies going bust!). The best you can do is get the [end result](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Directions).

Comment: thanks. It looks like I could fake my project by creating a custom kml for say the city I live in. but this is not optimal.

who needs car navigation companies anyway?